# Perl 5.8.8 - Curses interface - Multiple select - Is this possible?

Tags: perl, curses, solaris-10

A client has an old Solaris setup running 5.8.8, is it possible to have use [Curses](http://search.cpan.org/~giraffed/Curses-1.28/Curses.pm) to create a multiple select UI like the following example?

From the documentation I can't identify if this is possible, there seems to be no examples.

[image: Debian Config example:]

Comment: What you see is not a listbox or something similar, but a number of checkboxes. Therefore, *yes* it is easily doable.

Comment: @Matthias thanks, I don't see checkbox in the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~giraffed/Curses-1.28/Curses.pm)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be [Curses::UI](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI-0.9609/lib/Curses/UI.pm) in combination with [Curses::UI::Listbox](http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI-0.9609/lib/Curses/UI/Listbox.pm), which appears to offer the functionality which you are looking for.

I am not exceedingly familiar with Curses::UI, so I can't offer better examples than are already present in the pages to which I've linked--but even if you can't use this, perhaps you can use the module code to infer how it's manipulating Curses to offer this functionality.